Roboto isn't working on Outlook web [Content Builder MCSF]
I'm trying to use the Roboto font in some emails, and in the content builder it actually shows the font working, but when I send it to Outlook it doesn't show the font correctly, it reverts to the default Outlook font. Is there any way to make this work?
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
      body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 10pt;
            color: #000;
        } 

[![Content Builder][1]][1]
[![Outlook][2]][2]
Print from Content builder:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/65Gc28dB.png
Print from Outlook:
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/pzSmoHtf.png

To my knowledge, that is "expected" and there is little you can do:
source for all of the below: https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Web fonts only work in some email clients. That means you need to understand whether the font you want to use is supported and how to set up a fallback.
Since web font support is hit-and-miss across email clients, it’s a
good idea to analyze where your subscribers typically open emails. If
most of your subscribers use an email client supporting web fonts, try
it. If you find your audience is mainly on a non-web font-supportive
email client, you can avoid wasting time and effort.



*(ish? Some of the webfonts were showing up but it may be that the fonts were loaded on the computer)
**(Google overrides fonts – default on Android is Roboto, on iOS looks like Helvetica)
***(Fonts overridden – Roboto is default sans-serif)
****(ish. Liked Roboto, so there’s limited support of very specific web fonts – probably specific ones from Google Fonts, possibly only Roboto since it’s Google’s default)

